# Can I reset my BIOS password by programming my BIOS chip with a CH341A programmer?

Tags: boot, laptop, bios, motherboard

I have an ASUS G731GU laptop and I forgot my BIOS password. there is no CMOS battery and shorting the pins but it didn't work. I found out that the BIOS chip is a Winbond 25Q80EWNIG and I have a CH341A programmer with a test clip. I was wondering if I can use the programmer to flash a new BIOS image to the chip and reset the password. Has anyone done this before? Is it safe and easy to do? What software and files do I need? Any tips or advice would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The CMOS battery is the main battery, if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

See the article
[How I Removed my Forgotten BIOS Administrator Password?](https://infosecwriteups.com/how-i-removed-my-forgotten-bios-administrator-password-8dca33844023)

It shows how to use the programmer to load a new `.bin` BIOS into
the chip. This installing requires the programmer software on
another computer.

There is no point in my duplicating this article here.
I just wish to state that any error in the process and in the
manipulation of the BIOS chip is very dangerous for your computer.